# Как правильно тестировать данный сценарий?

Tags: php, юнит-тесты, phpunit

Есть функция обработчик. Она принимает в себя ассоциативный массив, который является отображением колонка=>значение в Базе данных. Чтобы не возникало ошибок, перед этой функцией вызывается фильтр, который отсекает лишние данные.

Задача: написать правильный тест фильтра.

Проблема: если поменять логику фильтра, но не поменять функцию обработчик, то прод падает, а тест выдает ОК.

Опишу более подробно:

Наш фильтр пропускает только ключи с значением "foo","bar". Написаны тесты, все работает ок. Пришло задание расширить функцию тестирования до "foo","bar","zero".

Разработчик, который отвечает за фильтр - дописывает еще 1 ключ в фильтр. Разработчик, который отвечает за обработчик - по той или иной причине не дописывает функционал.

Это приводит к тому, что на проде выходит ошибка, а в тестах показывается "ОК", так как сами тесты не менялись.

Как правильно написать полезный тест? Или изменена логика - нужно после внесения изменений в логику менять и тест, чтобы он работал адеквтано, но разве это правильно? Разве при изменении логики тест не должен падать?

Код и сценарий:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/57907c081d83a4c4ef75d3b1baa61b6c73ba2176

```
<?php
//входные данные теста
$testData=['foo','bar','fbar'];
//входные данные прода
$inputData=['foo','bar','foobar'];
//входные данные прода после изменения фильтра
$inputData2=['foo','bar','foobar','zero'];
//фильтр
$filter=['foo','bar'];
//Обновленный фильтр
$updateFilter=['foo','bar','zero'];


function filter($filter,$data){
    return array_intersect($filter,$data);
}
//обработчик, по своей сути падает, когда приходят левые данные. 
function handler($data){
    return count(array_diff($data,['foo','bar']))===0;
}

// тест 
$data = filter($filter,$testData );
echo "Тест: ";
var_dump(handler($data));
//прод
$data = filter($filter,$inputData );
echo "Прод: ";
var_dump(handler($data));

//Изменили фильтр и входные данные на проде, но не изменили handler

// тест 
$data = filter($updateFilter,$testData );
echo "Тест2: ";
var_dump(handler($data));
//прод
$data = filter($updateFilter,$inputData2 );
echo "Прод2: ";
var_dump(handler($data));
```

Результат:

```
Тест: bool(true)
Прод: bool(true)
Тест2: bool(true)
Прод2: bool(false)
```

Есть вот такой вариант решения проблемы, но это некий оверхед мне кажется...

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3827266d510e7d8c311c430dad4e590b50c2489b

```
<?php
//входные данные теста
$testData=['foo','bar','fbar'];
//входные данные прода
$inputData=['foo','bar','foobar'];
//входные данные прода после изменения фильтра
$inputData2=['foo','bar','foobar','zero'];
//фильтр
$filter=['foo','bar'];
//Обновленный фильтр
$updateFilter=['foo','bar','zero'];



class filter{
    private $foo,$bar;
    public function __construct($filterArray){
        $this->foo = $filterArray['foo'] ?? null;
        $this->bar = $filterArray['bar'] ?? null;
    }
    public function getData(){
        $data=[];
        foreach($this as $key=>$val){
            $data[$key]=$val;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}

class filter2{
    private $foo,$bar, $zero;
    public function __construct($filterArray){
        $this->foo = $filterArray['foo'] ?? null;
        $this->bar = $filterArray['bar'] ?? null;
        $this->zero = $filterArray['zero'] ?? null;
    }
    public function getData(){
        $data=[];
        foreach($this as $key=>$val){
            $data[$key]=$val;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}

//обработчик, по своей сути падает, когда приходят левые данные. 
function handler($filter){
    $data = $filter->getDaTa();
    $filterProps=[];
    foreach((new ReflectionClass($filter))->getProperties() as $prop){
        $filterProps[]=$prop->getName();
    }
    return count(array_diff($filterProps,['foo','bar']))===0;
}

// тест 
$filter = new filter($testData );
echo "Тест: ";
var_dump(handler($filter));
//прод
$filter = new filter($inputData );
echo "Прод: ";
var_dump(handler($filter));

//Изменили фильтр и входные данные на проде, но не изменили handler

// тест 
$filter = new filter2($testData );
echo "Тест2: ";
var_dump(handler($filter));
//прод
$filter = new filter2($inputData2 );
echo "Прод2: ";
var_dump(handler($filter));
```

Comment: а селектом из базы брать те что нужно нельзя и не замарачиваться?

Comment: Это тест. Естественно, что из базы берется то, что нужно. 
К тому же, тут логика обратная. Надо записать в базу. Т.е. прилетают данные, мы фильтруем, записываем.